# Get the size of an area defined by 2 overlapping circles

Tags: circles

I have two circles, like this:

[image]

I know the radii of the circles, and I know the X + Y of the center of both circles.

Can I get the size of the area that is black in my picture?

Comment: I've tried asking a Math and a Physics teacher, they both didn't know ^^

Comment: Google finds this: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

Comment: Oh my, that looks crazy complicated.
Isn't there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean easier to understand or easier to implement? Because equation 14 is pretty easy to implement. Just code up the expression and don't think about it too much. :) (And for what it's worth, I wouldn't hold out hope for a simpler formula. Areas of intersections tend to have complicated closed forms.)

Comment: Alright, thanks. Should I post it as an answer now? (I suppose I should)

Comment: If I were you, I'd ping @lhf and see if they want to post the answer first. And I just did. :)

Comment: The solution on mathworld only works if the y coordinate of the centers is the same so in order to generalize it you have to set 1 circle to be at (0,0) and the second circle at position (Distance between centers,0). This essentially transforms the more complicated problem into one that this equation can solve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A formula for the area is worked out in [Circle-Circle Intersection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) at Wolfram MathWorld:
$$
A = r^{2}\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{d^{2}+r^{2}-R^{2}}{2dr}\right)
+ R^{2}\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{d^{2}+R^{2}-r^{2}}{2dR}\right)
- \frac12 \sqrt{(-d+r+R)(d+r-R)(d-r+R)(d+r+R)}
$$
where $r$ and $R$ are the radii and $d$ is the distance between the centres.

Answer (score 6):

[This link](https://web.archive.org/web/20180422082904/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54785.html) helped me out in this situation. The MathWorld version is very descriptive, but I think the above link explains what is going on more clearly. I created a javascript function for this purpose, given below in case it is useful to anyone else.

```
function areaOfIntersection(x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1)
{
  var rr0 = r0*r0;
  var rr1 = r1*r1;
  var c = Math.sqrt((x1-x0)*(x1-x0) + (y1-y0)*(y1-y0));
  var phi = (Math.acos((rr0+(c*c)-rr1) / (2*r0*c)))*2;
  var theta = (Math.acos((rr1+(c*c)-rr0) / (2*r1*c)))*2;
  var area1 = 0.5*theta*rr1 - 0.5*rr1*Math.sin(theta);
  var area2 = 0.5*phi*rr0 - 0.5*rr0*Math.sin(phi);
  return area1 + area2;
}
```