# A simpler method to find the area of systems of inequalities in the complex plane

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, alternative-proof

Find the area of the region of points $z$ in the complex plane such that $$\begin{align*}|z+4-4i| &\leq 4\sqrt 2\\
|z-4-4i| &\geq 4\sqrt 2.\end{align*}$$

*Source: Art of Problem Solving (AoPS) Intermediate Algebra.*

Note: My solution is below.  I request verification but also simpler solutions.  The problem is marked intermediate algebra, but to solve it, I had to use trig  which is not officially required for this course, **implying there is a simpler solution**.

---

**Solution:** The area is $16(4 - \pi)$.

**Proof:** The equations define two circles, which we'll call $P'$ and $Q'$:

$$\begin{align*}P'&: \text{Center: } -4 + 4i \quad \text{ Radius: } 4 \sqrt 2\\
Q'&: \text{Center: } 4 + 4i \quad \quad \text{ Radius: } 4 \sqrt 2.\end{align*}$$

We want the area of $P' - P' \cap Q'$.  To simplify things, we'll dilate everything down by $4 \sqrt 2$, giving us $$\begin{align*}P&: \text{Center: } -\frac{\sqrt 2}2 + \frac{\sqrt 2}2i \quad \text{ Radius: } 1\\
Q&: \text{Center: } \frac{\sqrt 2}2 + \frac{\sqrt 2}2i \quad \quad \text{ Radius: } 1.\end{align*}$$

These are two unit circles with distance between their centers $d = \sqrt 2$.  As shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734007/what-is-the-area-of-intersection-of-two-unit-circles-whose-centers-are-d-units?noredirect=1#comment10036269_4734007), letting $\phi = 2 \arccos \frac d 2 = \frac \pi 2$, the area of the intersection is $$\phi - \sin \phi = \frac {\pi} 2 - 1.$$  Therefore, $$\text{Area } [P - P \cap Q] = 1 - (\frac \pi 2 - 1) = 2 - \frac \pi 2$$ and $$\text{Area } [P' - P' \cap Q'] = \left (4 \sqrt 2 \right )^2 (2 - \frac \pi 2) = 16(4 - \pi).$$

Comment: How do you even define the area of a region in the plane if geometry is not to be used?

Comment: @DavidK Fair enough - I edited the question to say "**trig** is not required."  And if we can't find a "simpler" solution: is my solution correct?

Comment: You don't need trig to recognize an isosceles right triangle. Hence you get the areas of the triangles in your other post by the formula $\frac12ab$ (which is actually $\frac12a^2$ when $a=b$).

Comment: @DavidK Aha! $PX = 1, PM = \frac {\sqrt 2} 2,$ so $MX =  \frac {\sqrt 2} 2$ by Pythagorean Theorem, and $A_{\triangle PMX} = \frac 1 4$.  And since $\theta + \theta + \frac \pi 2 = \pi$, we have $\theta = \frac \pi 4,$ and $A_{\text{sector } PSX} = \frac \pi 4$. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Write $w=z-4i$, which amounts to a translation, so we intersect the the disk $\mathcal D$ centered in $-4$ with radius $4\sqrt 2$ with the exterior of the disk $\mathcal D'$ centered in $4$ with same radius:
$$
\begin{align*}
|w+4| &\leq 4\sqrt 2\ ,\\
|w-4| &\geq 4\sqrt 2\ .
\end{align*}
$$
Picture proof:

[image: area computation for the intersection of a disk with the exterior of the other disk]

Let $A,B,C,D$ be the points on the axes at distance $4$ from the origin, as shown in the picture.
The square $ABCD$ has sides equal to $4\sqrt 2$.
We need the area of the disk $\mathcal D$ centered in $A$ and radius $AB=AD=4\sqrt 2$ after removing the $BD$-reflected disk $\mathcal D'$ from it.
The needed area is the brown region, $\frac 34\cdot \pi AB^2$, plus the square area $AB^2$, minus the orange area $\frac 14\cdot \pi CD^2$, this is:
$$
\left(\frac 34-\frac 14\right)\pi(4\sqrt 2)^2+(4\sqrt 2)^2
=
\frac 12\cdot\pi\cdot 16\cdot 2+ 16\cdot 2
=
16(\pi+2)
\ .
$$